# Seemingly simple task of looping for a string in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some trouble getting a loop to work in Excel VBA which searches cell E in each row for a string and then puts that string in cell N of that row.  Code is below:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
Next i
If Cells(i, 5).InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("ActiveCell").Value, "Smith") > 0 Then
Cells(i, 14).ActiveCell = "Smith"
End If
```

Can anyone please give insight as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: See [For](https://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C1AFAB_enCA478CA535&es_sm=93&q=for+microsoft+loop+vba&oq=for+microsoft+loop+vba&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30l2.882.1329.0.1840.4.4.0.0.0.0.438.438.4-1.1.0....0...1c.1.51.serp..3.1.438.5yVjo0E7BNo).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 5).InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("ActiveCell").Value, "Smith") > 0 Then
        Cells(i, 14).ActiveCell = "Smith"
    End If
Next i
```

You were ending your loop before it even did anything.

I think you also need to replace

```
Cells(i, 14).ActiveCell = "Smith"
```

With

```
Cells(i, 14).Value = "Smith"
```